# C++ exception inheritance ambiguity

Tags: c++, inheritance

Why does this work?

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

#include <boost/exception/all.hpp>

struct foo_error : virtual boost::exception, public std::runtime_error
{
    explicit foo_error(const char* what)
        : std::runtime_error(what)
    { }

    explicit foo_error(const std::string& what)
        : std::runtime_error(what)
    { }
};

struct bar_error : virtual boost::exception, public std::runtime_error
{
    explicit bar_error(const char* what)
        : std::runtime_error(what)
    { }

    explicit bar_error(const std::string& what)
        : std::runtime_error(what)
    { }
};

struct abc_error : virtual foo_error, virtual bar_error
{
    explicit abc_error(const char* what)
        : foo_error(what), bar_error(what)
    { }

    explicit abc_error(const std::string& what)
        : foo_error(what), bar_error(what)
    { }
};

static void abc()
{
    throw abc_error("abc error");
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        abc();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what();
    }
}
```

I thought this shouldn't compile due to the ambiguous conversion from `abc_error` to `std::exception`. What am I missing? I came up with the inheritance diagram, and I can't really figure out why this code works (the arrows denote virtual inheritance and the lines denote non-virtual inheritance).

```
  std::exception                  std::exception
        +                               +
        |                               |
        |                               |
        +                               +
std::runtime_error              std::runtime_error
        +                               +
        |                               |
        |   +-->boost::exception<-+     |
        +   |                     |     +
   foo_error+<-----+         +--->+bar_error
                   |         |
                   |         |
                   |         |
                   +abc_error+
```

It looks like `abc_error` includes two instances of `std::exception` so the `catch` (or so I thought) shouldn't be able to cast `abc_error` to `std::exception`. Or should it?

**UPDATE**

I can't answer my own questions at the moment, so I'm going to continue here. I've narrowed the problem down to:

```
struct NonVirtualBaseBase { };
struct NonVirtualBase : NonVirtualBaseBase { };

struct VirtualBase { };

struct A : virtual VirtualBase, NonVirtualBase { };
struct B : virtual VirtualBase, NonVirtualBase { };

struct C : A, B { };

int main()
{
    try
    {
        throw C();
    }
    catch (const VirtualBase& e)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The sample above works as expected and is a perfectly fine piece of code. It crashes if I replace `catch (const VirtualBase& e)` with `catch (const NonVirtualBase& e)` which I think is sane and makes sense. *But* it also works if I replace the same line with `catch (const NonVirtualBaseBase& e)` which to me seems odd and wrong. A compiler bug?

Comment: +1 for the well formatted code, nice question with explanation and cool ASCII art :)

Comment: Which compiler is this?

Comment: @Agentlien It's
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for x64

Comment: I've narrowed the problem down to a small piece of code, if anyone interested. A compiler bug? I don't know.

Comment: "I thought this shouldn't compile" There is nothing that would prevent this from compiling. Ambiguous base for an exception object is a run-time error. The code shouldn't run, and it doesn't run with gcc and clang.

Comment: "But it also works if I replace the same line with `catch (const NonVirtualBaseBase& e)`" It doesn't. Your compiler is buggy.

Comment: @n.m. I'm sorry, it was three years ago. The compiler shipped with Visual Studio 2012 (or whatever the version was) was indeed buggy. And I clearly shouldn't fix grammar/formatting in my older questions, as it for some reason spurred a great deal of new comments!

Comment: I even answered this question back then.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by the OP, this explanation doesn't quite cut it, since `std::exception` is not derived from using virtual inheritance. I believe the answer to be that this is actually undefined behaviour and simply not caught at compile time because there is no need for the `throw` and `catch` to know of each other and warn if they are incompatible.

**END UPDATE**

The answer is that this hierarchy uses**virtual inheritance** to derive from `boost::exception`.

Since both `foo_error` and `bar_error` uses virtual inheritance to inherit from `boost::exception`, there will only be a single `boost::exception` base which is shared between both the `foo_error` and `bar_error` sub-objects of an `abc_error`.

When you specify `virtual` before an entry in the list of base classes, this means all occurences of this class as a virtual base class in the most derived object will actually refer to the same instance. It is used specifically to avoid ambiguity in this type of design.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't ask if I tried to catch `boost::exception`. But I'm trying to `catch` `std::exception`, not `boost::exception`, which is included via non-virtual inheritance.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's just that I'm not able to get this straight in my head! How many instances of `std::exception` does an `abc_error` instance include? I thought it's 2, one from `foo_error` and one from `bar_error`. Hence the conversion to `std::exception` should be ambiguous. I know that conversion to `boost::exception` is OK, since an `abc_error` instance includes just one instance of `boost::exception` (since it's inherited `virtual`ly, not like `std::runtime_error`).

Comment: @EgorTensin Actually, it was my mistake. I read your diagram incorrectly. After reading your comment, I've concluded that I cannot explain this either.

Comment: @EgorTensin Experimenting, I realized that this only works due to the virtual inheritance used on abc_error to inherit from foo_error and bar_error.

Comment: I replaced `struct abc_error : virtual foo_eror, virtual bar_error` with `struct abc_error : foo_error, bar_error` and the thing still works. My brain hurts.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42122/discussion-between-agentlien-and-egor-tensin)

Answer (score 1):

> Why does this work?

For some loosely defined values of "work".

```
me@mybox > g++ -o test test.cpp
me@mybox > ./test
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'abc_error'
Aborted (core dumped)
me@mybox >
```

Comment: Strange... I got `>main.exe abc error` after `>cl /I"C:\boost\boost_1_55_0" main.cpp`

Comment: I'm getting that from cl too. Strange it is not :)

Answer (score 1):

It has to compile, because there's no reason you can't have multiply-defined base classes in exceptions, and no reason you can't have that base class in an exception declaration somewhere. The fact that `abc` happens to throw a particular thing, and that `main` happens to catch a particular thing, and that those things are frenemies, cannot be compile-time checked.

What it WON'T do is catch the exception properly, or at least it shouldn't. But I can see how a particular compiler might end up (incorrectly) doing that, because of how exception declarations are matched.